# QComboBox not updating the index

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

[image]

When I printed the item text of the combo box just to see if the value is changing when I change the current text value of the combo box, I found out that it isn't changing but staying at the 0 index value. How do I get the current text value of the combo box?

Comment: Possible you need to use `currentText()` instead `currentIndex()`. But general showing source code in screenshot is a bad idea.

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions: [combobox not being dynamic with qpushbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348278/combobox-not-being-dynamic-with-qpushbutton).